# Using SQL calculate average value on each sector

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

Can you please help me , on how to calculate the average value of the returns on each sector.

**Excepted Output **

| Stocks | Returns | Sector |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MS | 5.0 | IT |
| Apple | 5.0 | IT |
| GEICO | 5.0 | IT |
| PETRO | 8.5 | OIL |
| BP | 8.5 | OIL |
| Citiz | 7.0 | ENERGY |
| Utility | 7.0 | ENERGY |

This is what I have tried - But I don't see the expected result

```
create table table1
(
Stocks varchar(20),
Returns decimal(10,2),
Sector varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO table1 (Stocks,Returns,Sector) VALUES ('MS','2','IT')
INSERT INTO table1 (Stocks,Returns,Sector) VALUES ('APPL','5','IT')
INSERT INTO table1 (Stocks,Returns,Sector) VALUES ('GEICO','8','IT')
INSERT INTO table1 (Stocks,Returns,Sector) VALUES ('PETRO','10','OIL')
INSERT INTO table1 (Stocks,Returns,Sector) VALUES ('BP','7','OIL')
INSERT INTO table1 (Stocks,Returns,Sector) VALUES ('Citiz','10','ENERGY')
INSERT INTO table1 (Stocks,Returns,Sector) VALUES ('Utility','4','ENERGY')

select Stocks,AVG(Returns) as 'Returns',Sector from table1 group by Stocks,Returns,Sector
```

Comment: FYI, if you are both grouping and aggregating on the same column, this often denotes a problem. The `AVG` of the same same makes little sense, as it'll *always* be the value. The average of gives 1's is 1, the average of ten 9's is 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a *Group Aggregate*:

```
Select
   Stocks
  ,AVG(Returns) OVER (PARTITION BY Sector) AS 'Returns'
  ,Sector 
from table1
```

Comment: It's called a "windowed" aggregate, FYI. A group aggregate would be what the OP already has.

Comment: @kumassrunk: this approach is more efficient (and also more elegant) than the group by / join solution, because it scans the table only once (as opposed to at least twice with the self-join).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `inner join` to join the list of averages by sector

```
select t.Stocks, s.average, t.Sector
from table1 t
inner join (
  select Sector, AVG(Returns) as 'average'
  from table1 
  group by Sector
) s on s.Sector = t.Sector
order by Sector
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/p3EKjLIG)